# CMake output in Eclipse CDT console

Tags: eclipse, console, cmake, eclipse-cdt

Making project through command line behaves as expected and provides neat and colored output:

[image]

However, when invoking make through Eclipse - I get the following garbage:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project New2 ****

make -C debug -j all 
make: Entering directory `/d/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug'
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -H"/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2" -B"/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug" --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles/progress.marks"
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/d/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug'
make -f CMakeFiles/go.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/go.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/d/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug'
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 8
[ 12%] [34m[1mGenerating moc_GLWidget.cxx
[0m/D/Software/Qt/4.8.0/bin/moc.exe @moc_GLWidget.cxx_parameters
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "MSYS Makefiles" "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2" "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2" "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug" "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug" "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles/go.dir/DependInfo.cmake" --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug'
make -f CMakeFiles/go.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/go.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/d/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug'
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 1
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 2
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 3
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 4
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 5
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 6
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 7
[ 25%] [ 37%] [ 50%] [ 62%] [ 75%] [ 87%] [100%] [32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/go.dir/Perfomance.cpp.obj
[0m[32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/go.dir/Camera.cpp.obj
[0m/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DLL -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_DEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g @CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/go.dir/Perfomance.cpp.obj -c "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/Perfomance.cpp"
[32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/go.dir/main.cpp.obj
[0m[32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/go.dir/moc_GLWidget.cxx.obj
[0m[32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/go.dir/Milliseconds.cpp.obj
[0m[32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/go.dir/Keyboard.cpp.obj
[0m[32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/go.dir/Seconds.cpp.obj
[0m/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DLL -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_DEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g @CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/go.dir/Camera.cpp.obj -c "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/Camera.cpp"
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DLL -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_DEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g @CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/go.dir/moc_GLWidget.cxx.obj -c "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/moc_GLWidget.cxx"
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DLL -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_DEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g @CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/go.dir/Keyboard.cpp.obj -c "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/Keyboard.cpp"
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DLL -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_DEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g @CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/go.dir/main.cpp.obj -c "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/main.cpp"
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DLL -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_DEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g @CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/go.dir/Seconds.cpp.obj -c "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/Seconds.cpp"
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DLL -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_DEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g @CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/go.dir/Milliseconds.cpp.obj -c "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/Milliseconds.cpp"
[31m[1mLinking CXX executable go.exe
[0m/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E remove -f CMakeFiles/go.dir/objects.a
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/ar.exe cr CMakeFiles/go.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles/go.dir/objects1.rsp
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g    -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/go.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o go.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libgo.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  /D/Software/Qt/4.8.0/lib/libQtOpenGLd4.a /D/Software/Qt/4.8.0/lib/libQtGuid4.a /D/Software/Qt/4.8.0/lib/libQtCored4.a -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug'
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles"  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[100%] Built target go
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug'
/D/Software/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start "/D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug/CMakeFiles" 0
make: Leaving directory `/d/Users/Haroogan/Development/Eclipse CDT/Workspace/New2/debug'

**** Build Finished ****
```

There is no coloring, but that's understandable. However, the output structure is completely messed up and appears to be grouped in a wrong way. Furthermore, this "`[0m[32`" garbage is the most annoying feature :)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to configure/generate your project with `-DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=OFF`.

Comment: Yeah, that helped with the garbage, but unfortunately not with wrong grouping. However, I've noticed that removing `-j` flag from `make` fixes the problem. It seems like output synchronization is broken when using multi-threaded `make`.

Comment: Right, i'm experiencing this even with plain Makefile generator.